# Phonegap: Showing audio controlls and meta informations of my audio stream in the lockscreen and the dropdown status bar

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, audio, mobile

I wrote my first working android app for phonegap 5.1 playing an audio stream. As I cant find results: How can i show audio controlls and meta informations of my audio stream in the lockscreen and the dropdown status bar?

I'm using the org.apache.cordova.media plugin.

Answer (score 4):

My advise, use https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications - I used it on android, with latest lollipop you should be able to display card notifications that has action buttons.

It should be fairly easy to tweak the plugin to add your action buttons. Check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

For the actual contents of the notification (Song title, length,...) you would need to populate this yourself using your Media plugin APIs.

Answer (score 2):

## 1. Lockscreen

To do that you'll need to write some native code. There's a Phonegap Plugin which can customize the lockscreen displaying audio controls and more, but **it only works for iOS**: https://github.com/shi11/RemoteControls.

Using the Cordova Command Line Interface, type this to install `RemoteControls`:

```
cordova plugin add com.rd11.remote-controls
```

And use the following code each time you want to update the lockscreen:

```
var params = [artist, title, album, image, duration, elapsedTime];
window.remoteControls.updateMetas(function(success) {
    console.log('Metas successfully updated!');
}, function(fail) {
    console.log('Duh! Something nasty happened');
}, params);
```

## 2. Notification

I couldn't find any existing plugin to display a persistent notification with player controls, so for that you'll have to create a custom plugin or make use of a `JavascriptInterface`.

Comment: Nice plugin but looks like it's only IOS

Comment: But how does the native android player or like every music app doing it? I guess not with phonegap^^.